# Replace delimiter in csv that is not between square brackets

Tags: regex, unix, csv, sed

I have a lot of csv files that I am having trouble reading since the delimiter is ',' and one of the fields is a list with comma separated values in square brackets. As an example:

```
first,last,list
John,Doe,['foo','234','&3bar']
Johnny,Does,['foofo','abc234','d%9lk','other']
```

I would like to change the delimiter to '|' (or whatever else) to get:

```
first|last|list
John|Doe|['foo','234','&3bar']
Johnny|Does|['foofo','abc234','d%9lk','other']
```

How can I do this? I'm trying to use sed right now, but anything that works is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know it could be possible through sed or awk but you could do this easily through perl.

```
$ perl -pe 's/\[.*?\](*SKIP)(*F)|,/|/g' file
first|last|list
John|Doe|['foo','234','&3bar']
Johnny|Does|['foofo','abc234','d%9lk','other']
```

Run the below command to save the changes made to that file.

```
perl -i -pe 's/\[.*?\](*SKIP)(*F)|,/|/g' file
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but also helped me realize theres even more issues with the format of my original files >:X

Answer (score 0):

If it's always 2 values before the list, you could make use of the `limit` argument to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) in perl:

```
perl -pe '$_ = join "|", split /,/, $_, 3' list
```

This splits on commas up to a maximum number of 3 fields, then joins them back together with a pipe. The `-p` switch means that each line of input is stored as `$_` and processed before, then `$_` is printed.

Output:

```
first|last|list
John|Doe|['foo','234','&3bar']
Johnny|Does|['foofo','abc234','d%9lk','other']
```